# How do you use `delete` on a function?

Tags: solidity, function

"If a function type variable is not initialised, calling it results in a failed assertion. The same happens if you call a function after using `delete` on it." is a quote from
the official Solidity documentation on [Function Types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.2/types.html#function-types)

How do you "use `delete` on a function", though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete a function. What you can delete, though, is a variable that **points to** a function.

The documentation, likely, meant to say "The same happens if you call a function after using delete on a Function Type variable that points to that function".

Here's an example contract illustrating this scenario:

```
contract Test {
    // Variable pointing to a function
    function() internal pure pFunc;

    function foo() internal pure { }

    function das() public {
        // Initialize the function pointer
        pFunc = foo;

        // Execute the function via the function pointer
        pFunc();

        // Delete the function pointer variable
        delete pFunc;

        // Call the deleted function pointer (results in the tx being reverted)
        // If the line below is commented out, however, the function executes alright
        pFunc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Right... But, getting back to the quote from the documentation in light of what you said: how do you "call a function after using delete on it"?..

Comment: @Iaroslav You could write `pFunc()` but it will fail because it no longer point to a valid function.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details! I've accepted your answer and edited it to better align it with the question.

Answer (score 1):

In Solidity, the delete keyword is used to reset or clear the state of a variable or an array. However, it does not have any effect on the functions themselves.

Comment: So, is the official documentation wrong?